# Undefined mixin sass

Tags: vue.js, sass, nuxt.js

I get error undefined mixin when i use @include in components

I work in NuxtJs, install sass-loader, node-sass

Component

```
<style lang="scss">
.cardSmall {
  @include mq(laptop) {
    width: 720px;
  }
}
</style>
```

My mixin in assets/variables.scss

```
@mixin mq($breakpoint) {
  @if $breakpoint==laptop {
    @media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
      @content
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, code images are forbidden here. Please share code as text only.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nuxt imports several things automatically such as components and composables. But it doesn't auto-import (sass) mixins. Therefore you need to add an import to the top of your `<style />` tag:

```html
<style lang="scss">
@use "@/assets/variables.scss";

// ...
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, but its works with @import